# Reading multiple lines from binary file

Tags: python

I have a binary file, and I want to read its content,
Here's the code

```
with open ('file1', 'rb') as fp:

itemlist = pickle.load(fp)
print(itemlist)
```

and the code I am using to write to the file is

```
with open('file1', 'ab') as fp:

pickle.dump(training, fp)
```

The file contains many length 4 lists.
The problem is print(itemlist) is just printing the last list 
while I want all of them to convert to 2-D numpy array.I can even see the file size increasing gradually with every append call.

How can I do it?

Comment: are you writing to the file multiple times and appending to it each time? If so, the read will only read the first object (e.g. list) that you pickled. You'll need to loop around the pickle.load to read all of the objects.

Comment: A binary file has no lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many length 4 lists, you should dump and load them as a list of length 4 lists. Otherwise you would have to call `pickle.load` repeatedly until the file is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Build the 2d list first and after you save it. In this way, you don't need to write/read multiple times the file.

For example:

```
   import pickle
   training = []

   list1 = [2,4,5,6,7,7,2,6]
   list2 = [5,6,53,6,75,3,53,65]
   list3 = [46,89,24,64,243,25,6]
   list4 = [78,875,24,24,64,363,25]

   training.append(list1)
   training.append(list2)
   training.append(list3) 
   training.append(list4)

   with open('file1', 'ab') as fp:
       pickle.dump(training, fp)


   with open ('file1', 'rb') as fp:
      itemlist = pickle.load(fp)
      print(itemlist)
```

The output:

```
  [[2,4,5,6,7,7,2,6], [5,6,53,6,75,3,53,65], [46,89,24,64,243,25,6], [78,875,24,24,64,363,25]]
```